# Оптимизация запроса. Фильтр по столбцу mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть таблица продукции и атрибутов 1 к n.

```
p_id desc
1    tovar1
2    tovar2

p_id attr_id val
1     23     "hello"
1     34     "FDFD"
```

Нужно отфильтровать по множестве атрибутов, нормально ли писать множественные джоины или как можно лучше?

```
select t1.* from tovar t1 inner join attr t2 on (t2.p_id=t1.p_id) inner join attr t3 on (t3.p_id=t1.p_id) where (t2.attr_id=23 and t2.val="hello") and (t3.attr_id="34" and t3.val="FDFD")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это соответствует вашим намерениям?

```
select t1.p_id, `desc` from tovar t1 
inner join attr t2 on (t2.p_id=t1.p_id) 
where (t2.attr_id=23 and t2.val='hello') or (t2.attr_id=34 and t2.val='FDFD')
group by t1.p_id, `desc`
having count(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Старайтесь избегать `or` где это возможно, ибо будут тормоза из-за того, что индексы эффективно использоваться не будут.
У вас правильный запрос, но лучше переписать (с точки зрения читабельности и легкости модификации под другие условия) в таком виде:

```
select t1.* 
from tovar t1 
  inner join attr t2 on t2.p_id=t1.p_id and t2.attr_id=23 
  inner join attr t3 on t3.p_id=t1.p_id and t3.attr_id=34
where 
  t2.val="hello"
  and t3.val="FDFD"
```

т.е. часть с join'ами фиксированная, а where может меняться, так сложнее будет запутаться.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему это ненормально.

Может лучше так:

```
select t1.* from tovar t1 
inner join attr t2 on (t2.p_id=t1.p_id) 
where (t2.attr_id=23 and t2.val="hello") or (t2.attr_id="34" and t2.val="FDFD")
```

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, теперь он вернет мне даже если будет только один атрибут из них, а мне чтобы учитывались оба.

Comment: тогда вместо **or** поставить **and**, как у вас, только один inner join

Comment: Тогда если два атрибута, то строка возвращаться не будет. На стек оверфлов я спросил ответили так 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565081/best-way-to-filter-results-of-one-to-many-relation-query-mysql/18565157?noredirect=1#18565157
select p.*
from product p join
     attrib a
     on p.pid = a.pid
group by p.pid
having sum(a.aid = 1 and a.val = 'avalue1') > 0 and
       sum(a.aid = 2 and a.val = 'avalue2) > 0;